# Safe memory region for stack canaries

Tags: function, gcc, memory, assembly, stack

I want to implement a per-function call stack canary. Therefore I have to use a (not too small) memory region to put the canaries in (to check the stack value of the canary against the initial canary value). I have seen that gcc's stack protector uses the FS memory. There it only needs a very small memory region (I think its about 5 integers size). I have also read, that FS memory is used for other OS purposes, thus I obviously need to try not to disturb these purposes. Since I am implementing a per-function call canary I would need a bigger memory (canaries are 1 word big and I should be able to hold at least 100 canaries). Overall I am curious where I can safely put them.

Comment: You don't put stack canaries in `fs:`, you put them on the stack.

Comment: yeah but you put them somewhere in fs to check against the correct canary value

Comment: @Corn: You could improve this question if you edit in some of the info from comments on Ira's answer, like that this is a school project, and doesn't necessarily have to be efficient enough for real use.  And just generally clear up what the point is, and how you want it to work.  I think you have a good question, and it would make stackoverflow a better site if you'd tidy it up so it's clear to future readers what exactly is being asked.  (i.e. re-edit your question and I will probably upvote it.  :P  Maybe multiple smaller paragraphs?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are proposing to modify GCC to manage another kind of stack canary (doesn't it already have one?).

Are you proposing to keep a "parallel" psuedo-stack to the main stack with that psuedo stack pointer accessible via FS?  That's easy enough to implement using thread local store accessible via FS.  But ... why? Why can't you put the stack canary in the stack allocated for the function call?

I build a compiler (nothing to do with GCC) that has stack canaries.  It allocates space at the very bottom of each stack frame to hold a canary value (a constant but you could make be a value derived from the function's definition).    Since the compiler is generating the (function call/exit) code, on function entry it can write the canary constant into the stack frame, and on exit it can add a test against an immediate value for the same constant, against the canary in stack.   There is no need for a parallel stack, or any special use of FS or any other register to implement stack canaries this way.

Comment: yes you are right. i actually didnt think about just putting the canary value at the very bottom of each stack frame. i will try it out and maybe see if i have some further questions. thx

Comment: regarding to your question of gcc stack canary. yes they have one, but the stack canary is global afaik. which means u have the same value for each function. my implementation has an individual canary for each function call, which is safer. however this is a university assignment and not actually meant to replace gcc's stack canary